# Make it possible to ONLY select one row in datagrid?

Tags: winforms, select, datagridview

I want my datagrid to only allow one row to selected.

I guess I can do this by adding code to the datagridviews selectionChanged-event, but is there a better solution?

I would prefer to just have a property to set, i.e. :    `mydatagridview.maximumNrOfRowsSelected = 1`; or something similar.
Is there anything like this?

Answer (score 80):

The *DataGridView* has a Property called [MultiSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.multiselect.aspx) ( *default True* ).

Set this to **False**.

Answer (score 14):

I guess it has changed. Right now the correct way for WPF is:

```
<DataGrid SelectionMode="Single"> ...
```

in your XAML file.

Comment: Wrong answer ... this is a winforms question, not a WPF question.

Answer (score 1):

Adriaan's answer didn't work for me, but Oscar's got me on the right track. Maybe something changed since Adriaan posted.

To get it working for me I changed `SelectionMode` to `FullRowSelect`.

Comment: It's just that Adriaans answer is suited for WinForms and Oscars for WPF they are 2 seperate UI frameworks. (although the question specifically requested an answer for WinForms...)